# Read data from a DataGridView Cell and store it into a ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview

I'm a little bit overwhelmed. I have a DataGridView with a table which consists of five columns. Now when one or more row(s) are selected by the user and I click a Button I want to store two elements of these selected rows in a ListView. How to do that? Sorry for posting no code but I really don't know how to start with this (except for a foreach loop). Is there a way to get the cell value by the column name? Thanks!

EDIT:
I have some code for the beginning but it's completely wrong i guess...

```
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionQuery))
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.SelectedRows)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView4.Columns)
                    {
                        if (col.Name == cusIdBox.Text)
                        {
                            //DO
                        }

                        if (col.Name == cusNameBox.Text)
                        {
                            //DO
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks I've got a solution:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.SelectedRows)
                {
                    cusId = row.Cells[cusIdBox.Text].Value.ToString();
                    cusName = row.Cells[cusNameBox.Text].Value.ToString();

                    cusIdCells.Add(cusId);
                    cusNameCells.Add(cusName);
                }
```